# jQuery works offline, but not online

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is what what the JS does to my HTML, it inserts some style, the picture below has the normal code on the BOTTOM (offline) and the non-working code on the TOP (online).

[image]

So could someone have a look at my site and try to figure out why the heck it isn't working? I've double checked so many times.

http://chronox.comxa.com/

The section in question is right down the bottom, just above the email form, it's a gallery that obviously isn't loading right because the JS doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks

Comment: look for errors thrown in browser console

Comment: error shown in chrome `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).interactive_bg is not a function`

Comment: @Shomz Do you see the gallery correctly, like this?http://i.imgur.com/j4Z3TqS.png

Comment: @Celine Working fine for me and i'm seeing the gallery fine try clearing your cache?

If it's still not working try hosting the jquery files through jquerys cdn instead?

Comment: Actually no, I see only the first image, but no console errors. An ad-blocker is blocking your file, is `http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php` something you have control over?

Answer (score 0):

You have an ad-blocking software which prevents the file `http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php` to load.

If I disable my ad-blocker, I get this error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).interactive_bg is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):420m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2
```